# Dynamic Regex find and replace pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

My aim is to turn something like this:

```
src/com/company/folder/anotherfolder/manyfolders/filename.java
```

into this:

```
a few words com.company.folder.anotherfolder.manyfolders filename "description"
```

I've got it mostly to work with the following find and replace:

Find: `(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)(\..*)`

Replace: `a few words $2\.$3\.$4\.$5\.$6\.$7\.$8\040$9\040"description"`

Which works okay, however I may have different number of folders, so it won't work in that case.

How can I make it so that it works for any number of folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are carrying out two distinct processes here:

1. Replacing *all* `/` by `.`
2. Adding text before and after the replacement result and some other minor changes.

This is not possible with a single regex and if you still want to do it with the find/replace function of notepad++, you will need to do two replaces. I suggest the below replaces:

1. Replace `/` by `.` (no need for regex here, but if you have `/` you don't want to replace, then it becomes more complex and you might to use a regex like `(?:(?!^)\G|)\K/(?=[^.\r\n]*\.)` for the find and `.` for the replace).
2. Regex replace of

   ```
   [^.\r\n]+\.((?:[^.\r\n]+\.)+[^.\r\n]+)\.([^.\r\n]+)\.[^.\r\n]+
   ```

   And replace with

   ```
   a few words $1 $2 "description"
   ```

I am using this regex with the assumptions that folder and filenames can contain spaces and occupy a full line.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a few regexes in a row:

1. Convert slashes

   ```
   /
   ```

   =>

   ```
   .
   ```
2. Convert the rest

   ```
   ([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)\.(\w+)\.java
   ```

   =>

   ```
   a few words $1 $2 "description"
   ```

Comment: it would suit me much better to be just a single regex find and replace, is there no way to combine our two since mine does it in one step but yours does it dynamically

Comment: Nope, sorry. Regex is powerful but it doesn't have that functionality - to do multiple different kinds of replacement in a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to repeat on the `/` character - have you tried something like:

```
((.*)/)(.*)
```